# How can I mock a library in jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to mock the file-type library in a jest test. In my javascript file, I use this library in the following way:

```
import * as fileType from 'file-type';

....
const uploadedFileType = fileType(intArray);
```

Then, in my jest test, I am doing:

```
jest.mock('file-type');
import * as fileType from 'file-type';
```

and then trying to mock out the response in the following way:

```
fileType = jest.fn();
fileType.mockReturnValue({ ext: 'jpg' });
```

However, I get the error `"fileType" is read-only.`

Does anyone have an idea as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

If you only need the same return type in all test you can mock it like this

```
jest.mock('fileType', () => ({
  ext: 'jpg'
}))
```

This will mock the module so `fileType()` will always return `{ext: 'jpg'}`.

If you need different return values during your test you need to mock the module so it returns a spy where you can set the mock result later in the test using [`mockImplementation`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn):

```
import fileType from 'fileType'
jest.mock('fileType', () => jest.fn())

fileType.mockImplementation(() => ({
  ext: 'jpg'
}))
```